# react native expo with sqlite3

Tags: react-native, sqlite, expo

I have a problem that has been bothering me for more than 6 days, I have tried everything but I have not had satisfactory results. That's why I'm asking for your help. I created a database thanks to sqlite studio, it generated a .db file that I imported into my project directory at the root even I copied it. In this database I have inserted data that I want to recover to place in my form developed in react native expo. in my register.js file, I want to retrieve this data and display it on different drop-down menu. But when I open the database and select, I have an error which tells me that the selected table does not exist. yet it exists and contains data.

My database :

```
CREATE TABLE Provinces (
  province_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  nom_province TEXT
);

CREATE TABLE Antennes (
  antenne_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  nom_antenne TEXT,
  province_id INTEGER,
  FOREIGN KEY (province_id) REFERENCES Provinces (province_id)
);

CREATE TABLE CentresInscriptions (
  centre_inscription_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  nom_centre_inscription TEXT,
  antenne_id INTEGER,
  FOREIGN KEY (antenne_id) REFERENCES Antennes (antenne_id)
);

CREATE TABLE BureauxVotes (
  bureau_vote_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  nom_bureau_vote TEXT,
  centre_inscription_id INTEGER,
  mot_de_passe TEXT,
  FOREIGN KEY (centre_inscription_id) REFERENCES CentresInscriptions (centre_inscription_id)
);
```

App.js :

```
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
import Register from './Register';

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName='Register'>
        <Stack.Screen name="Register" options={{headerShown: false}} component={Register} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

Register.js

```
import { View, Text, TouchableOpacity, Image, TextInput, ScrollView } from 'react-native';
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { themeColors } from "./theme";
import { SafeAreaView } from 'react-native-safe-area-context'
import { ArrowLeftIcon } from 'react-native-heroicons/solid';
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { Picker } from '@react-native-picker/picker';
import * as SQLite from 'expo-sqlite';

const db = SQLite.openDatabase("mydb.db");

export default function Register() {
  
  const navigation = useNavigation();
  const [fullName, setFullName] = useState('');
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
  const [selectedProvince, setSelectedProvince] = useState('');
  const [selectedAntenne, setSelectedAntenne] = useState('');
  const [selectedCentre, setSelectedCentre] = useState('');
  const [selectedBureau, setSelectedBureau] = useState('');
  const [provinces, setProvinces] = useState([]);
  const [antennes, setAntennes] = useState([]);
  const [centres, setCentres] = useState([]);
  const [bureaux, setBureaux] = useState([]);
  
  useEffect(() => {
    
    db.transaction(tx => {
      tx.executeSql(
        'SELECT * FROM Provinces',
        [],
        (_, { rows }) => {
          setProvinces(rows._array);
          console.log('Provinces:', rows._array);
        },
        (_, error) => {
          console.log('Error during select:', error);
        }
      );
    });
  }, []);

  const handleProvinceChange = (value) => {
    setSelectedProvince(value);

    db.transaction(tx => {
      tx.executeSql(
        'SELECT * FROM Antennes WHERE province_id = ?',
        [value],
        (_, { rows }) => {
          setAntennes(rows._array);
          console.log('Antennes:', rows._array);
        },
        (_, error) => {
          console.log('Error during select:', error);
        }
      );
    });
  };

  const handleAntenneChange = (value) => {
    setSelectedAntenne(value);

    db.transaction(tx => {
      tx.executeSql(
        'SELECT * FROM CentresInscriptions WHERE antenne_id = ?',
        [value],
        (_, { rows }) => {
          setCentres(rows._array);
          console.log('Centres d\'inscriptions:', rows._array);
        },
        (_, error) => {
          console.log('Error during select:', error);
        }
      );
    });
  };

  const handleCentreChange = (value) => {
    setSelectedCentre(value);

    db.transaction(tx => {
      tx.executeSql(
        'SELECT * FROM BureauxVotes WHERE centre_inscription_id = ?',
        [value],
        (_, { rows }) => {
          setBureaux(rows._array);
          console.log('Bureaux de votes:', rows._array);
        },
        (_, error) => {
          console.log('Error during select:', error);
        }
      );
    });
  };

  const handleRegister = () => {
    console.log('Full Name:', fullName);
    console.log('Email:', email);
    console.log('Password:', password);
    console.log('Selected Province:', selectedProvince);
    console.log('Selected Antenne:', selectedAntenne);
    console.log('Selected Centre:', selectedCentre);
    console.log('Selected Bureau:', selectedBureau);
  };
  

  

  return (
    <ScrollView contentContainerStyle={{ flexGrow: 1 }}>
      <View className="flex-1 bg-white" style={{ backgroundColor: themeColors.bg }}>
        <SafeAreaView className="flex">
          <View className="flex-row justify-start">
            <TouchableOpacity
              onPress={() => navigation.goBack()}
              className="bg-blue-400 p-2 rounded-tr-2xl rounded-bl-2xl ml-4"
            >
              <ArrowLeftIcon size="20" color="black" />
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
          <View className="flex-row justify-center">
            <Image source={require('./images/logo.png')}
              style={{ width: 165, height: 110 }} />
          </View>
        </SafeAreaView>
        <View className="flex-1 bg-white px-8 pt-8"
          style={{ borderTopLeftRadius: 50, borderTopRightRadius: 50 }}
        >
          <View className="form space-y-2">
            <Text style={{ color: 'gray', marginLeft: 10 }}>Provinces</Text>
            <View className="p bg-gray-100 text-gray-700 rounded-2xl mb-3">
              <Picker
                selectedValue={selectedProvince}
                onValueChange={handleProvinceChange}
              >
                <Picker.Item label="Katanga" value="" />
                {provinces.map((province) => (
                  <Picker.Item
                    key={province.province_id}
                    label={province.nom_province}
                    value={province.province_id}
                  />
                ))}
              </Picker>
            </View>
            <Text style={{ color: 'gray', marginLeft: 10 }}>Antenne</Text>
            <View className="p bg-gray-100 text-gray-700 rounded-2xl mb-3">
              <Picker
                selectedValue={selectedAntenne}
                onValueChange={handleAntenneChange}
              >
                <Picker.Item label=" Antenne 1" value="" />
                {antennes.map((antenne) => (
                  <Picker.Item
                    key={antenne.antenne_id}
                    label={antenne.nom_antenne}
                    value={antenne.antenne_id}
                  />
                ))}
              </Picker>
            </View>

            <Text style={{ color: 'gray', marginLeft: 10 }}>Centre d'inscription</Text>
            <View className="p bg-gray-100 text-gray-700 rounded-2xl mb-3">
              <Picker
                selectedValue={selectedCentre}
                onValueChange={handleCentreChange}
              >
                <Picker.Item label="Centre 1" value="" />
                {centres.map((centre) => (
                  <Picker.Item
                    key={centre.centre_inscription_id}
                    label={centre.nom_centre_inscription}
                    value={centre.centre_inscription_id}
                  />
                ))}
              </Picker>
            </View>
            <Text style={{ color: 'gray', marginLeft: 10 }}>Bureau de vote</Text>
            <View className="p bg-gray-100 text-gray-700 rounded-2xl mb-3">
              <Picker                selectedValue={selectedBureau}
                onValueChange={setSelectedBureau}
              >
                <Picker.Item label="Bureau 1" value="" />
                {bureaux.map((bureau) => (
                  <Picker.Item
                    key={bureau.bureau_vote_id}
                    label={bureau.nom_bureau_vote}
                    value={bureau.bureau_vote_id}
                  />
                ))}
              </Picker>
            </View>
            <Text className="text-gray-700 ml-4">Code secret</Text>
            <TextInput
              className="p-4 bg-gray-100 text-gray-700 rounded-2xl mb-7"
              secureTextEntry
              value={password}
              onChangeText={setPassword}
              placeholder="Enter Password"
            />

            <TouchableOpacity
              className="py-3 bg-blue-400 rounded-xl"
              onPress={handleRegister}
            >
              <Text className="font-xl font-bold text-center text-gray-700">
                ENVOYER
              </Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>

        </View>
      </View>
    </ScrollView>
  )
}
```

The error I have : Error during select: [Error: no such table: Provinces (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM Provinces]

Thank your for answers